# PyTest 404 on testing a delete endpoint

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have CRUD endpoints that Im writing tests for, some of these require a ID to get and delete etc and of course when i come to test them it requries an ID to be presant in the database to
allow the tests to pass.

My question is, is there a way with PyTest that will allow for this not to be the case and that the let say delete test ill pass each time?

Or is it a case tha tthe tests have to interact with the database each time they are run?

My test file:

```py
import json

import pytest
from . import app
from mock import patch


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return app.test_client()


# Define a fixture that mocks the verify_jwt_in_request function
@pytest.fixture
def mock_verify():
    # Create a mock object
    mock = patch("flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request")
    # Start the patch and return the mock object
    yield mock.start()
    # Stop the patch
    mock.stop()


@patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
def test_access_issues_upload(mock_verify, client):
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    headers = {'Content-Type': mimetype}
    data = {
        'date_time': '2020-05-21',
        'asset_label': '123456',
        'external_ref': '123',
        'building_name': 'Hilton',
        'floor': 'one',
        'room': '123',
        'reason': 'Cant enter',
        'description': 'description',
        'asset_id': '1',
        'picture': {
            'url': 'http://example.com',
            'width': 1200
        }
    }

    response = client.post('/access-issues/create', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.content_type == 'application/json'
    assert b'Success: Access Issue Created Successfully' in response.data


@patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
def test_access_by_id(mock_verify, client):
    response = client.get('/access-issues/get/3')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'Success: Access Issue fetched Successfully' in response.data


@patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
def test_sites(mock_verify, client):
    response = client.get('/access-issues/get')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'Success: Access Issue fetched Successfully' in response.data


@patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
def test_sites_delete(mock_verify, client):
    response = client.delete('/access-issues/delete/3')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'Success: Access Issue Deleted Successfully' in response.data
```

Comment: It would be important to ensure your tests do not depend on each other. They should all be atomic. You should check to see if the database library you are using provides a mock version or in-memory for testing. Some of them provide a pytest-*** library. It will facilitate what you are trying to do. You can then create a fixture around that and attach pre and post controls every time a test is run. From there, all you have to do is create what you need inside your test for what you need, and then the fixture will take care of clearing it out for the next test. Something like that.

Comment: The hard part is finding where to mock it out from so that you override your real database setup and replace it with the fixture. So you will need to determine from what entrypoint of your code can you properly reference and catch where you setup your database engine so you can override it with the fixture you are setting up. Once you get that, it should come together nicely.

Comment: If your database setup for your test framework is setup correctly, then I would say your best bet is to setup the environment you need inside each test to ensure each of your tests run atomically, and then wherever you have setup your database mocking, when you yield back to the fixture you just clean things up so the next test iteration is using a clean environment.